# VBA Runtime Error : Clear Contents of an Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have written following VBA code in Excel 2003 to clear the contents of an excel sheet;
But it shows

> RunTime Error 438: Object doesn't Support this property or Method

Here is my code,

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\a.xls")
wbk.Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents 'Error at this line
wbk.Save
wbk.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Could any one please let me know if **wbk.Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents** is not supported when excel is invisible. How can I clear content of an excel sheet when it is invisible?

Comment: Try `wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents`

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Great! Its working; You can add it as an answer... Thanks

Comment: That's Ok :) You can also answer your own questions :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout in his case he is opening the workbook invisibly, is that right? :) Coz if it's fully closed then, there will not be a `workbooks.open` line. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @bonCodigo: Yup the workbook is opened in invisible mode but that is not the main issue here. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for that confirmation. Coz I was thinking perhaps OP would be looking for a closed book without any opening involved ;) I was concerned on the closed book part as issue is pretty obvious.

Comment: @bonCodigo: Yes! i am opening it invisibly. you highlighted(workbooks.open) good point. what should i use if i remove the line workbooks.open ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: could you pls tell me how to achieve the point said by bonCodigo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the following and it is solved now!

```
wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents
```

Comment: Btw, you should be able to approve your own answer.

Comment: @JüriRuut : yes, but it requires 16hrs to approve my own answer